# What happeded when a fd is redirected to itself

Tags: shell, file-descriptor

> background: I want to have a further understanding of dup and other techniques in Linux. And I tested in zsh

In documentations like [zsh(7)](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Redirection.html), common cases are listed like `2>&1`, but `1>&1` is not stated. When I tested,

```bash
echo a
a
echo a 1>&1
a
echo a 1>&1 1>&1
a
a
echo a 1>&1 1>&1 1>&1
a
a
a
a
```

This looks fine, as the output is duplicated again and again. But

```bash
echo a 1> >(wc -l)      
1
echo a 1>&1 1> >(wc -l) 
a
1
echo a 1> >(wc -l) 1>&1 
2
```

I'm confused with the order of execution. I can't find explanation to these rare usage. Can anyone helps to demonstrate by shell's implementation and/or features of `dup` and other syscalls?